# CD Ripping Metadata Software for SFX database

Tags: software

We are redoing our SFX server.  We use netmix pro along with netmix server on mac leopard and snow leopard.

I was wondering if there was a good CD ripping software that can tag the regions with its metadata.

I know soundminer has a ripper, however it is around $300 and we are trying to avoid an expense that high for the moment. The manuals for netmix (by creative network solutions) mentions a software called 'ripit' however they are referring to version 4 and they are on version 9 now, focusing on DVD ripping and not CD with metadata.

Comment: Another one for SD please Tim...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the Soundminer ripper and it works very well.  Depending on your libraries and which column you need the metadata embedded, have you tried Itunes?

Comment: yea, soundminer is the best...